# How to detect draw of last row in a Listview to retrieve the next set of data?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, compact-framework

I am looking for a way like Social Networks site retrieve additional data when the last record is visible to user.

How I am able to do that for a ListView in Compact Framework (c# mobile app).

**Still looking for answers 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do [a custom-drawn ListView](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2009/10/listview-custom-drawing-in-netcf.html).  Even if you simply use the base implementation for the draing, the CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT will tell you the index of the item it's trying to paint.  You can use that to determine where in the list you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you override ToString() on your objects, I would expect that you would get hit whenever the items are drawn.

Comment: My object is not on the `view` level it sits in the `model`.